# Transform table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've this Excel table

```
product_code    Component_code  severity    Count
GMFOPEN         GMFOPENAPP      HIGH        1
GMFOPEN         GMFOPENPROJECT  CRITICAL    5
GMFOPEN         GMFOPENPROJECT  HIGH        41
GMFOPEN         GMFOPENPROJECT  LOW         3
GMFOPEN         GMFOPENPROJECT  MEDIUM      39
GMFOPEN         GMFOPENPROJECT  SUGGEST     1
```

and I'd like to transform in this one

```
product_code    component_code  HIGH    CRITICAL    MEDIUM  LOW SUGGEST
GMFOPEN          GMFOPENAPP     1               
GMFOPEN          GMFOPENPROJECT 41         5         39      3     1
```

Any suggestion about which formulas to use without to use pivot table?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following <kbd>EXCEL FORMULA</kbd>. May be there is more compact approach, but this is what I have tried.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     data,SORTBY(A2:D7,XMATCH(C2:C7,{"HIGH";"CRITICAL";"MEDIUM";"LOW";"SUGGEST"})),
     a,INDEX(data,,1),
     b,INDEX(data,,2),
     c,INDEX(data,,3),
     d,INDEX(data,,4),
     ua,UNIQUE(a),
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     uc,TOROW(UNIQUE(c)),
     head,HSTACK(A1:B1,uc),
     VSTACK(head,IFERROR(HSTACK(ua,ub,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ub),COLUMNS(uc),LAMBDA(x,y,
     SUM((a=ua)*(b=INDEX(ub,x))*(c=INDEX(uc,y))*d)))),ua)))
```

---

I assume it will be more easier to do using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    CustomSort = Table.Sort(Source, each List.PositionOf({"HIGH","CRITICAL","MEDIUM","LOW","SUGGEST"},[severity])),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(CustomSort, List.Distinct(CustomSort[severity]), "severity", "Count", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Another approach as mentioned by **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)** Sir,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     b,B2:B7,
     c,C2:C7,
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     us,UNIQUE(c),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,TOROW(us)),
     HSTACK(LEFT(ub,7),ub,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ub),ROWS(us),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(D2:D7*(b=(INDEX(ub,x,)))*(c=(INDEX(us,y,)))))))))
```

---

Comment: `=LET(b,B2:B7,
     c,C2:C7,
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     us,UNIQUE(c),
VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,TOROW(us)),HSTACK(LEFT(ub,7),ub,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ub),ROWS(us),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(D2:D7*(b=(INDEX(ub,x,)))*(c=(INDEX(us,y,)))))))))
` but your formula version is more suitable for adopting in different datasets (and PowerQuery being a more logic choice).

Comment: @P.b Sir very nice. Let me repost it, if you permit